# How can I prevent date.getMillisOf null pointer exception?

Tags: java

There is a problem in `oldScoreByPriorityMap.get(key).getCalculationDate()`. How can I prevent the millis throwing null pointer exception in this section?

**Exception**

```
[29.05.2020 17|callto:29.05.2020 17]:01:37,619 ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Date.getMillisOf(Date.java:958)
        at java.util.Date.after(Date.java:931)
        at tr.com.model.report.objects.ReportTableObject.setOldScoreByPriorityMap(ReportTableObject.java:80)
        at tr.com.model.report.objects.ReportTableObject.setCpty(ReportTableObject.java:26)
```

**RaportTableObject.java**

```
    String key = scoreByPriority.getRuleEngineSetup().getName();
    if(oldScoreByPriorityMap.containsKey(scoreByPriority.getRuleEngineSetup().getName())) {
        if(scoreByPriority.getCalculationDate()!=null && scoreByPriority.getCalculationDate().after(oldScoreByPriorityMap.get(key).getCalculationDate()))
            oldScoreByPriorityMap.put(key, scoreByPriority);
    }else {
        oldScoreByPriorityMap.put(key, scoreByPriority);
    }
```

**Date.java**

```
public boolean after(Date when) {
    return getMillisOf(this) > getMillisOf(when);
}
```

Comment: `if(when==null)` ? Because it looks like the date itself is not instantiated (null)

Comment: how can i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be help you

```
    String key = scoreByPriority.getRuleEngineSetup().getName();
    if(oldScoreByPriorityMap.containsKey(scoreByPriority.getRuleEngineSetup().getName()) && oldScoreByPriorityMap.get(key).getCalculationDate() != null) {
        if(scoreByPriority.getCalculationDate() != null && scoreByPriority.getCalculationDate().after(oldScoreByPriorityMap.get(key).getCalculationDate()))
            oldScoreByPriorityMap.put(key, scoreByPriority);
    }else {
        oldScoreByPriorityMap.put(key, scoreByPriority);
    }
```

Comment: to be absolutely sure that in the case where you compare the two *score* dates, no nullpointer is thrown, this is the most direct approach. Before comparing dates, check that they exist. If you want a more generic approach you can put the null-test in your `after()` method: `return when!=null && getMillisOf(this)>getMillisOf(when);`  The idea is that any date is not "after" another date which does not even exist.

Comment: @GameDroids  It seems that okoreni's solution worked. Is not it?

Comment: sure it works. It's a good solution. Sorry for the complicated comment :)